# Bison/YACC - avoid reduce/reduce conflict with two negation rules

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc

The following grammar (where INTEGER is a sequence of digits) gives rise to a reduce/reduce conflict, because e.g. -4 can be reduced by expr -> -expr or expr -> num -> -INTEGER. In my grammar, num and expr return different types so that I have to distinguish -num and -expr. My goal is that -5 is reduced by num while e.g. -(...) is an expr. How could I achieve this?

```
%token      INTEGER

%left       '+'     '-'

%%

start: expr
    ;

expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | '-' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    | num
    ;

num:  INTEGER
    | '-' INTEGER
    ;
%%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving reduce/reduce conflict in yacc/ocamlyacc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516/resolving-reduce-reduce-conflict-in-yacc-ocamlyacc)

Comment: I saw this one before I posted this question, and I think that the answers might be similar (increasing the complexity of the grammar), yet I did not come up with a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, you could change the rule for negative expressions to

```
expr: '-' '(' expr ')'
```

and only recognize negations on parenthesized expressions.   This however won't recognize double-negatives (eg `- - x`) and, more importantly, won't scale in that it will break if you try to add other unary operators.

Now you could simply put the `num` rules BEFORE the `expr` rules and allow the default reduce/reduce conflict resolution to deal with it (the first rule appearing in the file will be used if both are possible), but that's kind of ugly in that you get these conflict warnings every time you run bison, and ignoring them when you don't know exactly what is going on is a bad idea.

The general way of addressing this kind of ambiguity is by factoring the grammar to split the offending rule into two rules and using the appropriate version in each context so that you don't get conflicts.  In this case, you'd split `expr` into `num_expr` for expressions that start with a `num` and `non_num_expr` for other expressions:

```
expr: num_expr | non_num_expr ;

num_expr: num_expr '+' expr
        | num_expr '-' expr
        | num
        ;

non_num_expr: non_num_expr '+' expr
            | non_num_expr '-' expr
            | '-' non_num_expr
            | '(' expr ')'
            ;
```

Basically, every rule for `expr` that begins with an `expr` on the RHS needs to be duplicated, and other uses of `expr` may need to be changed to one of the variants so as to avoid the conflict.

Unfortunately, in this case, it doesn't work cleanly, as you're using precedence levels to resolve the inherent ambiguity of the expression grammar, and the factored rules get in the way of that -- the extra one-step rules cause problems.  So you need to either factor those rules out of existence (duplicating every rule with `expr` on the RHS -- one with the `num_expr` version and one with the `non_num_version` OR you need to refactor your grammar with extra rules for the precedence/associativity

```
expr: expr '+' term
    | expr '-' term
    | term
;

term: non_num_term | num_term ;

non_num_term: '-' non_num_term
            | '(' expr ')'
;

num_term: num ;
```

Note in this case, the num/non_num factoring has been done on `term` rather than `expr`

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear on why `num` needs to represent negative numbers. I can't tell if you use `num` elsewhere in your grammar. You also don't say why you want `num` and `expr` to be distinct.

Normally, negative numbers are handled at the lexer level. In your case, the rule would be something like `-?[0-9]+`. This eliminates the need for `num` at all, and results in the following:

```
expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | '-' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    | INTEGER
    ;
```

**EDIT:** Chris Dodd has a point. So you need to move negation *entirely* into the parser. You still get rid of `num`, just don't test for negatives in the `INTEGER` lexer pattern (i.e. the pattern would be something like `[0-9]+`, which is what you're doing now, right?). The `expr` rule I gave above does not change.

- A negative number (`-5`) parses as: `'-' INTEGER`, which becomes `'-' expr` (choice 5), then `expr` (choice 3).
- A difference between two integers (`3-2`) parses as `INTEGER '-' INTEGER`, which becomes `expr - expr` (choice 5 twice), then `expr` (choice 2).
- A difference between an integer and a negative integer (`5--1`) parses as `INTEGER '-' '-' INTEGER`, which becomes `expr '-' '-' expr` (choice 5 twice), then `expr '-' expr` (choice 3), then `expr` (choice 2).

And so forth. The fundamental problem is you have negation in *two different places* and there is no way that can't be ambiguous.

Comment: This works poorly, as an input like `3-2` will be recognized as `INTEGER(3)` `INTEGER(-2)` by the lexer and cause a syntax error.